# Can You Spot the Answer?

Tags: riddle, word, poetry

> I am the aim, I bring guns to bear.
>   I can transport you from here out to there.
>   I can improve you in body and mind,
>   A series of thoughts, I may be dragged behind
>   Like kids' macaroni art back in the past
>   The first to reach anger is never the last

The result of these bizarre musings in rhyme is a single, common English word. Has the strain of giving up acrostics warped my mind or is there reason hidden in the ramblings?

Comment: I FOUND A WAY TO MAKE IT AN ACROSTIC. :)
First, III = 3, and ALT = alt. Take a look here. http://www.alt-codes.net/ Take the result and watch this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyT9jTW7MHc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're a:

> Train

I am the aim, I bring guns to bear.

> To *train* one's sight on a target.

I can transport you from here out to there.

> A locomotive *train* which transports people from here to there.

I can improve you in body and mind,

> Physical and mental *train*ing.

A series of thoughts, I may be dragged behind

> A *train* of thoughts to slowly lead you to a conclusion others have. The *train* of a bride's dress trails behind.

Like kids' macaroni art back in the past

> [image]
>  Duh, thanks to @question_asker and the man himself @Hugh got ***train oracam*** which is a bride's train behind her dress. *phew*
>  Still keeping the kid with the awesome macaroni train though :) )

The first to reach anger is never the last

> Again, oops thanks to @question_asker and @Hugh: The first letter of each word after the word "first" spells *train*, **damn** I was bad here!

Comment: Explain the last two lines and you get the tick. :)

Comment: This also covers the "___ spot" in the title and the "strain" in the question.

Comment: @question_asker totally lost on the last two but got so lucky with that picture couldn't resist :D

Comment: @question_asker lost, so lost... I gladly hand it over to you. I love that kid with his macaroni trains so much - no going back now :) ))))

Comment: The drag behind hint refers to part of a bride's dress. Two clues in one line just to confuse things. Hellion picked up on the title hint and the hidden word. The second word of the last line is a pointer as is the fifth word of the second last.

Comment: Yeah. I kind of want to change the riddle to accommodate the kid now.

Comment: OK, finally (maybe) got it after many thunks over the head with blunt instruments... ahhhhhrgggg :)

Answer (score 1):

> Sight(s)

I cannot figure it for all lines but...

> You use sights to aim a gun and bring it to bear. I can see far off places with sight. Insight improves my mind. "Hind-sight is always 20-20".